# How to set timeout lock for user account after some number of failed logins?

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, locking, increment, login-attempts

I have been working on login system for my app. After doing some research I saw that the best practice now days might be to lock the user account after some number of failed logins. This will prevent unauthorized users from trying/guessing password multiple times in a row. I'm wondering what would be the best way to implement this feature in my system? I have SQL 2008 to communicate to my database and ColdFusion 2016 on the back end. My query that will check `username` or `IP` and maybe `sessionID` looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(LoginID) AS count
FROM FailedLogins
WHERE LoginUN = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#FORM.username#" maxlength="50">
  OR LoginSessionID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#SESSION.sessionid#" maxlength="50"> 
  OR LoginIP = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#REMOTE_ADDR#" maxlength="20">
```

I'm not sure if I should be checking sessionID (J2EE session id). Also from the query results above I should be able to check if number of failed logins is 3 or greater then lock account for `5min` or if it's 6 failed attempts or more `10min`. Is there a good solution to implement this in coldfusion? I'm not sure what would be the best practice for this logic. If anyone can provide some example that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I would go 5 failed attempts and then give a 10 minute lockout. 3 attempts would be easy to legitimately make if someone couldn't remember the exact password they used. More than 5 though, would likely indicate that whoever it is either needs to use your Password Reset feature or they aren't a legitimate user.

Comment: @Shawn For locking process for some period of time what would be the best way to implement this logic? Is that some kind of delay or something else?

Comment: I would only log attempted username, IP address and a timestamp (generated by the SQL server itself). You can have a `isUserLocked` bit value in your database for the user, and set it to `true` when the failed login attempts exceeds your max. Then use a SQL job to check your failed logins table and clear the flag after x minutes.

Comment: On a successful login, clear the records for the user. Then after x minutes or hours, purge the records completely so you don't blow out your storage if someone is beating on your login. If you have an IP with repeated failed logins, pass it back to your network system and block that IP.

Comment: @Shawn This part is not completely clear to me `Then after x minutes or hours, purge the records completely so you don't blow out your storage if someone is beating on your login.` Also SQL job would have to run on let's say every 5min and 10min to check for the user with the flag `isLocked = true` and then I guess I need time stamp when user was locked. If difference is grater than 5 or 10 min change the flag status. Correct?

Comment: RE: purging >> You don't want someone to brute force away your database drive space and DOS your entire site because it can no longer write to the data drive. You'll want to monitor this. If someone hits you with a DDOS, you're hosed. And it would be better for your host to handle that at the network level. Those kinds of attacks should be detected and mitigated long before they even get to your application though. But you purge old failed logins because they don't have any meaning when they get old.

Comment: You wouldn't need to log the time that a user is locked out. It's already logged as the last failed login attempt.

Comment: @Shawn How then I would compare the time when user was locked? SQL job will check in Login table if user status flag is true. There is two different tables Login and LoginFailed. Login Failed table can have multiple records for the same user as you know so I guess the oldest record timestamp I would have to compare against current time?

Comment: You might also want to a simpler log of whoever it is that's repeatedly failing logins (and how many fails before a pass). If you see someone with a habitual problem, they may need to be addressed.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at instituting a reCaptcha.

Comment: The time of the last failed login would be the lock time. A successful login after failed logins from the same IP address could clear the failed logins. As you can see already, the topic of login practices is a very complex subject that's going to have a bazillion opinions and really is very dependent on what your system does and the UX you want to project.

Comment: @Shawn I see that and no one provided any example just some theory what could be good or bad. I'm not sure how to make decision since there is no rules that are defined for this kind of problem.

Comment: Also, as was mentioned over in InfoSec, check out https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks. Depending on what your system is, you may not want to lock out, but delay logins.

Comment: @Shawn I think that locking for some period of time (5min or 10min depends on # of failed attempts) could be the best fir for my system. Only what i'm not sure is how SQL job will run? Constantly or frequently since I need some kind of timer to clear the lock.

Comment: You won't need any timer. Just check the last failed login time and if it's >=x minutes earlier than current time, unlock it. You can schedule the SQL job to run every couple of minutes or so. It shouldn't be a very heavy operation. Are you expecting a lot of login attempts?

Comment: @Shawn It is state wide system so there might a lot of login attempts. I'm wondering if that can cause some problems since user might be locked longer than it should. (time difference since user was locked and until next job task runs).

Comment: Use the `locked until` method will keep users from having to wait until the next job run. But "locked longer than it should" totally depends on what's important in your system. You lock to prevent abuse, but you don't want to make your UX so poor that users bail. It's something you'll have to weigh in your system expectations.

Comment: @Shawn I have tried and `locked_until` seems like a good option. Only concern about that solution is what after time expires? If user reset the password they will successfully pass authentication and all failed attempts will be removed, but if they still enter incorrect password what then? Count will go up to 6 so I'm wondering what should be the  next step in that case?

Comment: If they are locked out until x time for failed logins, then they are locked out. If they successfully pass, then it's fine to clear their logs. If they fail again, then the logic will set them to be locked out again.

Comment: @Shawn That makes sense, I was wondering If I should maybe increase lock until time after 10 failed logins or not.

Comment: Your goal here is to make it as difficult as possible for someone to abuse your login system while making it only as difficult as necessary for your legit users. If a user locks themselves a couple of times because they are too stubborn to request a password reset, they'll probably get over that stubbornness after the second lock. If not, they'll stay locked out until they do. Those edge cases should probably be logged and dealt with elsewhere.

Comment: I would stick to 5. 10 is a lot for a legit user.

Comment: @Shawn Basically just keep updating locked until time after 5 failed logins. Every other failed login will result to locked until update until they successfully pass authentication.

Comment: Yes, essentially. By nature, 6 failed logins in a row will meet the requirement of 5 failed logins, and will result in locking the user for x minutes. Unless you've got a bad actor trying to slow play your brute force protections, this will likely drive them to an easier target. You can also do something like set a check so that after 10 logins, the user is completely locked and must initiate the password reset process. User login is a very involved subject.